# Excel crash after Copy and paste Chart image

Tags: excel, vba, crash, paste, excel-charts

I Need to Copy an picture/image of a chart which is in another workbook (WbO), and paste the picture in a worksheet in this workbook (TWb), using Excel vba.
I figured out a simple code to do this.
The good thing is that the code works. Stepping line by line throught the code everything completes perfectly.

However, if I run the code (no Stepping) it also runs until the end without any error and completes the job. BUT, by the end Excel Crashes **without any error message**, restarts and reopens the workbook. (all work lost).
The weirdiest thing is that **it crashes 3 to 5 seconds after ending the run**. 3 to 5 seconds is an enormous lenght of time for computing. What is it doing during this time??

For testing, I added a 'Msgbox "Completed", vbokonly' as last code line. This made vba stop and show the message, and no crash while the message is on screen. Clicking ok, the macro runs to the end and then, after some seconds ... Crash.

Searched for similar problems in the web and found some old posts refering errors related to copy/paste, but no complete crash like this.

Tried this same file/code in different PCs, both with up-to-date office 365 but different update channels (not same build). The result was exactly the same.

Tried changing the .CopyPicture statement to a normal Copy, and then using PasteSpecial as Picture. Same Result.

Even tried moving the copy/Paste instructions to different subs (suggestion from a 2018 post), and inserting DoEvents in between .. without any luck.

Does someone have a clue why this is hapenning?
How to overcome this issue?

Help welcomed

Sample code below:

```
Application.EnableEvents= False
Set WbO = /Workbooks.Open("WbOFileName",0)
Set ChrtObj= Worksheets("MyCharts").ChartObjects(1) 'Set handle to the Chart obj
TWb.Activate  ' Activate destination Workbook = The Wb which contains the macro

ChrtObj.CopyPicture
RangeToPasteOn(1,1).Select  ' Select Top-Left cell to paste the Chart on
ActiveSheet.paste         ' Paste the Chart
  ' ... here Code to ajust Size and position to fit destination range

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set ChartObj = Nothing   'Release handle
WbO.Close
Set WbO = Nothing
Application.EnableEvents= True
```